# Login-AzureRMAccount returns "Unknown User Type"

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-resource-manager

As the title implies, I'm trying to automate the login process to AzureRMAccount in Powershell.

I've scoured every forum on every website I can find trying every different combination of solutions (well, except for the solution that works).

Every time I try to automate the login process of my Azure account, I get an error :

> Unknown User Type

Yes, I have full access to this account, and Yes it does work fine if I omit all of the parameters and allow for the interactive username/password dialog.

I have even tried to simply call the `Get-Credentials` and push those into a variable and then call `Login-AzureRMAccount` using those creds....no luck.

`Add-AzureRMAccount` fails too.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I did find one solution, although it's not the most secure solution as it generates a disk file putting your information at risk if someone were to gain access to the machine on which the Powershell code is executing.

You can login interactively and immediately export the context to a json file, Then at a later time, import that json file as the current context to bypass login

```
PS C:\> Save-AzureRmContext -Profile (Add-AzureRmAccount) -Path C:\test.json
```

then in a later session, Import the context

```
PS C:\> Import-AzureRmContext -Path C:\test.json
```

Again, this is not the most secure option but it did achieve the results. I would love to have a more secure option.

Comment: For people without an Azure AD account (everyone who purchased their subscription with a MS live/outlook/hotmail account) this is the only working option. Excellent find!